# Connecting to Teradata from python using teradata module results in 'WSA E TimedOut'

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc, teradata

Iam trying to connect to Teradata from python using teradata module but it results in TimedOut.

the exception is:

```
(434, '[HY000] [Teradata][WSock32 DLL] (434) WSA E TimedOut: No response received when attempting to connect to the Teradata server')
```

is there any way to increase the timeout from python coding side?

attaching the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username=username,
                            password=password, LoginTimeout=60,driver="DRIVERNAME")      as connect:

Since it might be taking time to login, so you are facing the error.
You need to add a parameter LoginTimeout=60 which will solve the issue.